# make вычислить значение в правиле

Tags: bash, unix, shell, makefile

Не получается вычислить значение в правиле и записать его в переменную.

Есть вот такое правило:

```
elastic-load-balancer:
    $(info "running elastic load balancer of yandex cloud")
    COMMAND_VAR=...
    cd elb && terraform plan
    cd elb && terraform apply -auto-approve -var="yandex_compute_instance_group_id=${COMMAND_VAR}"
```

Вместо многоточия мне требуется подставить `cd instance_group && echo $(terraform output terraform_group_instance_id)` и записать в переменную результат выполнения команды `terraform output terraform_group_instance_id`.

Затем эту переменную нужно подставить ниже, в коде. Как это сделать?

---

**UPD**

```
$(info "running elastic load balancer of yandex cloud" ${cd instance_group/ && terraform output terraform_group_instance_id})
```

Ответ не подставляет. Если выполнить команду, то получу строку

Comment: В большинстве имплементаций `make`, включая *GNU Make*, каждая команда выполняется в отдельном процессе, так что очевидно, что переменные так работать не будут.  Либо используйте макросы, либо выносите код команд в отдельный *shell*-скрипт.

Comment: @Ainar-G с shell-скриптом тоже проблема. Гуглил, но не то, чтобы очень глубоко и много. Проблему понял. Окей. Буду в shell-script выносить

Comment: @Ainar-G не получается подставить ответ от скрипта или сам скрипт в код. (обновил вопрос)

Comment: Эм.  Вы какие-то странные вещи делаете.  Я говорил вам создать файл, напр. `1.sh`, и в вашем *make*-правиле вызывать его как `$(SHELL) ./1.sh`.

Comment: @Ainar-G я нечто подобное тоже делал. Но не зашло. Поэтому вытащил из 1.sh команды и развернул их

Comment: `COMMAND_VAR=$$(sh -c 'cd ~/tmp; ls -l'); \  echo $$COMMAND_VAR` прекрасно работает (это две строчки).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В большинстве имплементаций `make`, включая *GNU Make*,
каждая команда выполняется в отдельном процессе, так что очевидно, что
переменные так работать не будут.  Про вынос в скрипт я уже написал вам
в комментарии.  Вот вариант с макросами для *POSIX Make*:

```make
COMMAND_VAR = $$(echo foo)

elastic-load-balancer:
    @ echo "running elastic load balancer of yandex cloud"
    cd elb && terraform plan
    cd elb && terraform apply -auto-approve\
        -var="yandex_compute_instance_group_id=$(COMMAND_VAR)"
```

Comment: Так не канает, так как у меня есть правила, которые зависят друг от друга и они делают некоторые вычисления. Только после осуществления этих вычислений можно считать COMMAND_VAR. Поэтому COMMAND_VAR должен быть именно внутри правила

Comment: Я отказался от идеи использовать make, так как, судя по всему, я использую его не верно. Кроме того, это приносит больше боли и страдания, чем пользы. Ваш вопрос помечу, как верный, так как он отчасти решает проблему. Но, фактически, вопрос открыт

Comment: @hedgehogues  Возможно, это наилучшее решение.  `make` — прежде всего инструмент отслеживания зависимостей между файлами с целью сборки и обновления проектов.  Использовать его как «склад команд» можно, но надо знать его «приколы».

Comment: @hedgehogues, когда начинаешь понимать, что *make — функциональный язык программирования*, то всё становится гораздо понятнее (и про рекурсию тоже, которой в нём хватает). Ainar-G, и вам к сведению.

Comment: @0andriy могли бы Вы пояснить?

Comment: @hedgehogues, ну, если вы когда-нибудь писали на Lisp, то это то же самое, только с набором некоторых условностей.

Comment: @0andriy я понимаю, что такое ФП. Но не понимаю, как это применить к make. Кажется, что здесь да, можно рекурсию в правилах усмотреть. Но ФП... такое себе сравнение

Comment: @hedgehogues http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/85

Comment: @hedgehogues https://www.slideshare.net/mimimau/introduction-to-gnu-make-programming-language ну и так далее...

Answer (score 3):

как уже отметили в другом ответе, по умолчанию для каждой строки рецепта запускается новый экземпляр оболочки. напомню терминологию, используемую для [описания правила (rule)](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax):

```
цели : пререквизиты
    рецепт
    ...
```

итак. можно пойти разными путями:

1. например, объединить присвоение переменной и те команды, в которых она нужна, в «непрерывную» строку (если строка заканчивается символом `\`, то следующая за ней считается её непосредственным продолжением). т.е., заменить в рецепте:

   ```
       COMMAND_VAR=...
       cd elb && terraform plan
       cd elb && terraform apply -auto-approve -var="yandex_compute_instance_group_id=${COMMAND_VAR}"
   ```

   на что-нибудь вроде:

   ```
       COMMAND_VAR=... && \
       cd elb && terraform plan && \
       terraform apply -auto-approve -var="yandex_compute_instance_group_id=${COMMAND_VAR}"
   ```

   обратите внимание: я убрал один вызов *cd*. он получается лишним.
2. добавить в файл [специальную цель `.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html). в результате оболочка будет вызываться однократно на один рецепт, а не на каждую строку в каждом рецепте. учтите, что, например, количество тех же `cd` надо будет сократить.
3. но лучше, вероятно, будет изменить весь подход. так, чтобы он соответствовал основной парадигме программы *make*: отслеживанию зависимостей между **файлами** и выполнению рецепта (т.е., «обновлению» цели, она же — **файл**) только в том случае, если у цели обновился хотя бы один пререквизит (и пререквизиты — тоже **файлы**).

   в частности, начать можно с того, что результат выполнения программы, который вы записываете в переменную, записывать в **файл**.

   а этот файл уже поставить пререквизитом к другой цели, в рецепте которой у вас сейчас подставляется значение переменной, вместо чего можно читать информацию из файла.

   и т.д. и т.п.

---

всё-таки дополню: да, конечно, часто используются цели, файлам **не** соотвтетствующие (т.н. «[phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)»). главная их «проблема» в том, что они «рвут» основную парадигму программы *make*: обычная цель может **не** требовать обновления (если пререквизиты старше цели), а вот «phony»-цель требует обновления (выполнения рецепта) всегда. и того же она требует ещё и от тех целей, у которых записана в пререквизиты.

Answer (score 2):

Дополню предыдущий ответ, для ограничения области видимости можно так же писать

```
elastic-load-balancer: COMMAND_VAR = $$(echo foo)
    echo ${COMMAND_VAR}
    ...
```

Так же объявление можно вынести

```
elastic-load-balancer: COMMAND_VAR = $$(echo foo)
elastic-load-balancer:
    echo ${COMMAND_VAR}
    ...
```

и так тоже будет корректно

```
elastic-load-balancer:
    echo ${COMMAND_VAR}
    ...
...
elastic-load-balancer: COMMAND_VAR = $$(echo foo)
```